# _Unwind_ and unw_ functions (LLVM's libunwind)

Tags: c++, linux, llvm, stack-unwinding, libunwind

I'm new to the LLVM's libunwind library. Could you please tell me what's the purpose and the difference of the two sets of functions that libunwind provides:

1. functions with the prefix _Unwind_
2. functions with the prefix unw_

Answer (score 1):

`libunwind` is an implementation of the interface defined by the HP `libunwind` project. It was contributed by Apple as a way to enable clang++ to port to platforms that do not have a system unwinder. It is intended to be a small and fast implementation of the `ABI`, leaving off some features of HP’s `libunwind` that never materialized (e.g. remote unwinding).

The unwinder has two levels of API. The high level APIs are the `_Unwind_*` functions which implement functionality required by `__cxa_*` exception functions. The low level APIs are the `unw_*` functions which are an interface defined by the old HP `libunwind` project.

https://libunwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/